# SharePoint 2013 custom Attach File button

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, javascript

I'm trying to create a custom "Attach File" button in my SharePoint 2013 New Item form. So far this is what I've done:

HTML

```
 <div onclick="javascript:openpageindialog();" class="btn" style="float: left;">Attach File</div>
```

JS:

```
function openpageindialog() {
var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
options.title = "Attach File";
options.url = '/_layouts/Attachfile.aspx?ListId={My-ListId}&ItemId=4';
options.autoSize = true;
options.showClose = true;
options.showClose = true;
options.allowMaximize = false;
// options.dialogReturnValueCallback = callback;
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

This works just fine, but this the issue. As you notice I addded "***ItemId=4***" for testing purposes, but this a New Item form; therefore there is not ItemId yet. Is there any work around this? I would hate to create a New Item form and then add the Attach File button to an Edit Form after the Id has been created. Just FYI, unfortunately, I can't use any server side code Thanks!

Comment: SharePoint handles attachments on the New Item form already.

Comment: I encountered the same problem also, do you have any idea now?

Comment: Can you customize the form using Info-Path forms, that will provide the custom attach file button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Custom "New Form" Using SharePoint Designer. You will be able to see all the code for all fields, Now add a new attachment field there and bind it using xslt. Bewlow is  the code.

```
<SharePoint:AttachmentButton runat="server" id="attachmentnew" ControlMode="New" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i','attachmentnew','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"></SharePoint:AttachmentButton>
```

Comment: I already created a custom New Form, that's one of the reasons why I'm having the issue.I'll give a try to your suggestion next Monday, and I'll let you know how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Did you got through your problem ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I'm getting: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'insertRow' of null" error on the console. I'll keep playing around to see what's going on. Thanks for following up.

Comment: just try copy pasting this code, i works for me fine. Make sure you don't have the id which is used in this code. It should work fine.

Comment: new attachment field is of what type?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinvent it, the code is there and you need to call the function called "UploadAttachment()". For example, you can use a button to cal it:

```
<input type="button" value="Attach File" onclick="javascript:UploadAttachment()" />
```